# Access the navigation state in a screen without connecting to Redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to access the **full** navigation state in a screen without connecting to Redux.

I know I have the prop `navigation` which contains a `state` key in my screen but there is only the `key` and the `routeName` in it.
I want the full state with the `routes` hierarchy and so on (the same `react-navigation` stores internally and gives us in `navigationOptions`).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can track the navigation stack and screens with `onNavigationStateChange` prop. You can find more information [here in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/screen-tracking#Screen-tracking).

**Example**

```
export default () => (
  <AppNavigator
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
      const currentScreen = getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
      const prevScreen = getCurrentRouteName(prevState);

      if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
        // the line below uses the Google Analytics tracker
        // change the tracker here to use other Mobile analytics SDK.
        tracker.trackScreenView(currentScreen);
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: But I will need to store this somewhere. I can't access to that *directly* in my screen..

Comment: You can use asyncstorage to store it as a without redux solution. Another solution would be using a component with state and saving currentsState when the navigationState change to this components state and then passing this state variable to children as a screeenProp. This is a bit hacky solution but might work. [HERE](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51#issuecomment-323536642) is an example for it.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. I can use Redux but I needed that only for a `back` handler so it seemed overkill to wire the whole thing. I guess won't have the choice..